# Do I need to repeat glOrtho call after all my drawing code?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am creating 2D game with OpenGL. Everytime I move my object, I have to call `glLoadIdentity`, because otherwise all objects will be moved, but `glLoadIdentity` also resets `glOrtho` call, so basically I ending with something like this:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main()
{
glfwInit();

glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE );
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 8 );
glfwOpenWindow( 800, 600, 0, 0, 255, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW );

glfwSetWindowTitle( "title" );

glfwSwapInterval( 1 ); // also known as 'vsync'

glfwEnable( GLFW_KEY_REPEAT );
//glfwDisable( GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR );

glOrtho(0.0, 1024, 768, 0, -1.0, 1.0); 
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

while( !glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) )
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1024, 768, 0, -1.0, 1.0); 

    glTranslatef( 100, 0, 0 );

    glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex2f(100, 100);
      glVertex2f(100, 250);
      glVertex2f(250, 250);
      glVertex2f(250, 100);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1024, 768, 0, -1.0, 1.0); 

    glRotatef( 25,0,0,1);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex2f(300, 300);
      glVertex2f(300, 450);
      glVertex2f(450, 450);
      glVertex2f(450, 300);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();

    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

glfwTerminate();
}
```

How should it be done properly, to display, move and rotate objects with `glOrtho` enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(). Checkout this tutorial:

http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/pop_and_push_matrices.html

Comment: datenwolf's answer is more correct than than mine. Have a look at the diagram on this Web page: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html . It shows the major transformations, including the project matrix. -Aaron

Answer (score 6):

> but glLoadIdentity also resets glOrtho call, so basically I ending with something like this

glOrtho belongs into the projection matrix, not the modelview matrix. The answer you accepted is not conceptually wrong, but it did miss that part. That part of your code should look like

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1024, 768, 0, -1.0, 1.0); 

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef( 100, 0, 0 );

glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glVertex2f(100, 100);
  glVertex2f(100, 250);
  glVertex2f(250, 250);
  glVertex2f(250, 100);
glEnd();

glLoadIdentity();

glRotatef( 25,0,0,1);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glVertex2f(300, 300);
  glVertex2f(300, 450);
  glVertex2f(450, 450);
  glVertex2f(450, 300);
glEnd();

glFlush();

glfwSwapBuffers();
```